# Robot Standard library shows non-accessible in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, robotframework

Need help to resolve compilation/build issue for robot test suite in eclipse (RED plugin).
Problem: 
[Files under standard library are non-accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBZsv.png)

compilation failed for the below robot code from https://github.com/nokia/RED due to keyword "log" not recognized.

```
*** Keywords ***
myKW    
   log hi!
*** Test Cases ***
myTest
   myKW
```

**Environment**:
Robot Framework Version: 3.2.2 and also tried with latest
Python Version: 3.9.7 
Red plugin: Installed from eclipse market place (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/red-robot-editor)
Note: In Eclipse Window->Preference->Robot Framework as well as in red.xml the path to robot framework is correct

Comment: from the copy/paste it looks there are not enough spaces between 'log' and 'hi!'

Comment: I verified that there is enough space between log and hi.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the python version to 3.7.0 and robot framework to 3.2.2 resolved the issue